# What is another JQuery function that does something similar to is()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$target.is( "a.foo" )` will return true or false depending on if the target matches what's inside is().

What if I want to check what is() sees? What function do I use?

I tried `alert($(target.is())` to see if I could find out what the target is, but I just got the value false.

Comment: *"What if I want to check what is() sees?"* What does that mean? If you want to know how it works, have a look at the source code.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a function you can call on a jQuery object to return "a.foo", a string describing the element. The problem is, a target can be targeted a ton of different ways using jQuery, so there is no one single string that will describe what an element "is". An element can be "a" or "a.foo" or "a[href='foobar']" or "a.foo#bar[href='foobar']". All of these might match your target, but there is no way to call the inverse function.

Comment: did you try `$target.is.toString()` ?

Comment: function (selector) {
    return !!selector &&
        (typeof selector === "string" ? POS.test(selector) ? jQuery(selector, this.context).index(this[0]) >= 0 : jQuery.filter(selector, this).length > 0 : this.filter(selector).length > 0);
}

Comment: I found what a value to supply to is() that resulted in true by guessing. It doesn't look like any of the answers really tell you how to do any better than that, so I'm finding it hard to select  a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

> The target property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
     var $target = $(event.target);
     if( $target.is("a.foo") ) {
        ...
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but based on your topic, a similar jQuery function here would be `.hasClass()`.

```
$target.hasClass('foo'); // true if $target contains a className 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use is() to check some variables to return a function;
it is very similar to hasClass method..

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  $target = $(this);
  if(!$target.hasClass('active')) {//or u can use is('#active') to check id
                             //to prevent same response on same object hover
     $('a').removeClass('active');
     $target.addClass('active');
     $('.allPages').hide();
     var getID = $target.attr('id');
     $('#'+getID).show();

  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be a matter if using console.log on the object, and on the typeof of both the $target and a selector of a.foo?

ie

```
console.log($('a.foo'));
console.log(typeof($('a.foo')));
console.log($target);
console.log(typeof($target));
```

I assume this is what the .is() would be checking, testing the value and type of two objects, similar to '===' although I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/

example is here :

```
jQuery.type(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you want to find out if the target was found.
They way to do it:

```
if($target.length > 0){
    //found
}
```

If you want to get node name do:

```
$target.get(0).nodeName
```

Comment: No, I know that the target was found, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Edited answer if you want get node name like: div, li, form, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Because that is the information that is given to is().

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery objects maintain their original selector in a property:

```
var $target = $('#originalSelector');

alert($target.selector); // Alerts '#originalSelector'
```